# MySQL is not starting and it stops unexpectedly

Tags: mysql

After starting XAMPP server in windows 10, when I am trying to start MySQL it stops unexpectedly and showing some error to. Please check the attached error log.

I am using XAMPP and I haven't set any username and password for MySQL. For now, the Username is 'root' and the password is empty. It works for a few days. Later it's automatically asked for username and password to connect with MySQL. But I don't have any password because I didn't set that. Then I skipped that by adding 'skip-grant-tables' in my.ini file. And also increased cache memory 12MB to 128MB. And for now, it is refusing to connect with MySQL while I am opening my application. I have attached the error log below. Please check. All the help is appreciated !!

- 2019-07-25 13:59:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
- 2019-07-25 13:59:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
- 2019-07-25 13:59:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
- 2019-07-25 13:59:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
- 2019-07-25 13:59:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
- 2019-07-25 13:59:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
- 2019-07-25 13:59:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
- 2019-07-25 13:59:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
- 2019-07-25 13:59:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
- 2019-07-25 13:59:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
- 2019-07-25 13:59:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
- 2019-07-25 13:59:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
- 2019-07-25 13:59:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 4438406; transaction id 2678
- 2019-07-25 13:59:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
- 2019-07-25 13:59:11 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
- 2019-07-25 13:59:11 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

Comment: Server socket is created on IPv6 - are you sure that it also listens for IPv4 connections ?

Comment: *and showing some error to. Please check the attached error log*. Please add that part of your log file (usually at the end, not the beginning of your log).

Comment: I have same error. Do you have any solution to this?